# listing subpackages and functions installed in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, module, package

I'm really struggling with this. I'm trying to open the sklearn modules in order to see the versions installed as I'm having trouble with the packages and the code. Specifically, `xgboost`, `from sklearn import impute.KNNImputer`, and others. My system:

```
System:
    python: 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
   machine: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0

Python deps:
       pip: 19.2.3
setuptools: 41.4.0
   sklearn: 0.21.3
     numpy: 1.16.5
     scipy: 1.3.1
    Cython: 0.29.13
    pandas: 0.25.1
```

And it's not that easy to update, as I'm working with the office notebook so I don't have permission to update/install the packages at my will. So:

-How do I get a list of sklearn sub packages and versions? Like to see all the possibilities/packages and functions of:

```
from sklearn.subpackage import function1, function2 # this is my definition os subpackage and function, correct me if I'm wrong
from sklearn.subpackage2 import function10, function20, function30
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, make_pipeline
```

- With getting that list above will I know what `from sklearn import impute.KNNImputer` same/similar function was for an older version of sklearn? [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html#sklearn.impute.KNNImputer) you can see that `sklearn.impute.KNNImputer` it's for `0.22` sklearn version, and I have `0.21`. (So I'm willing to find in that list a similar function)
- Idem for `xgboost`, as it's a package installed separately, there has to be some `sklearn.xgboost` installed by default with sklearn, where using the list above I will be able to know which xgboost function/module I will be able to use.

So, I'm looking for a function/method that does something like:

```
sklearn.list_subpackages()
output: package (version 1.2), package2 (version 2.3), model_selection (version 5.1), metrics (version 10.1), pipeline (version 2.1)

package2.list_functions()
output: function10, function20, function30

model_selection.list_functions()    
output: train_test_split
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you run `conda prompt`?

Comment: if you mean Anaconda terminal, yes I can

Answer (score 0):

You have to navigate through your python package directory, open sklearn folder, find the subpackage file and right click on it and edit it by sublime text or other text editor or ide.... wait don't edit! Most modules and packages have their version number and description in them either as strings or commented lines like:

```
"""
This is the subpackage, version number blah blah and more information..
"""
from example import example
```

**but** you can store them in **variables** of the subpackages, like see this `__init__.py` file from keras(just see the last line), the code inside is like:

```
try:
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError(
        'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
        'Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`')

from . import utils
from . import activations
from . import applications
from . import backend
from . import datasets
from . import engine
from . import layers
from . import preprocessing
from . import wrappers
from . import callbacks
from . import constraints
from . import initializers
from . import metrics
from . import models
from . import losses
from . import optimizers
from . import regularizers

# Also importable from root
from .layers import Input
from .models import Model
from .models import Sequential

__version__ = '2.4.3'
```

As you can see in the last line.. `__version__ = '2.4.3'` you can do the same with the subpackage you want, read from the comment line, and make a variable version, store the version number, then you can easily access subpackages' variable in your function after importing them.

Comment: how do you find the sklearn folder? I installed it with anaconda, and when I go through its folder, there is like 40 folders and sub-folders very similar to "packages", "library", etc.